# Proof of identity involving vector field, unit tangent vector and a smooth curve.

Tags: vector-analysis, curves, vector-fields

Let $\textbf{t}$ be a continuous vector field which is parallel to the unit tangent vector at each point of a smooth curve C. 
Prove that,
$$
\int_{C} \textbf{t} \cdot d\textbf{r}=\int_{C} ||\textbf{t}|| d\textbf{s}\space.
$$

$C$ is parametrised by $<u,\frac{u^2}{2},\frac{u^3}{6}>$ and I have been given the points $(0,0,0)$ and $(6,18,36)$

Comment: Edit: This is my first question on here! I'm really stuck on how to approach this and have NO IDEA where to start so any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming we're working with three dimensions here, any curve can be parameterized in one variable (called a parameter), with some bounds on the parameter. (Usually the bounds are specified in an interval, e.g. $a \leq s \leq b$.) Let us assume that $\mathbf{r}(s)$ is a parameterization of $C$, and define $\mathbf{r}'(s)$ to be the derivative (tangent) vector at the point $\mathbf{r}(s)$ (the point on the curve corresponding to when the parameter is equal to $s$). What the left-hand side denotes is then is the *vector* line integral, which is by definition
$$\int_a^b \mathbf{t}(\mathbf{r}(s)) \cdot \mathbf{r}'(s) ds$$
However, it is also given that for any point $(x, y, z) = \mathbf{r}(s)$ which lies on the curve $C$, $\mathbf{t}(x, y, z)$ returns a vector parallel to the tangent vector at $\mathbf{r}(s)$, meaning that $ \mathbf{t}(\mathbf{r}(s))$ is actually always parallel to $\mathbf{r}'(s)$. We know that the dot product of two parallel vectors is just the product of their magnitudes, so it would follow that
$$\mathbf{t}(\mathbf{r}(s)) \cdot \mathbf{r}'(s) = \|\mathbf{t}(\mathbf{r}(s))\| \cdot \| \mathbf{r}'(s) \|$$
(The dot on the right-hand side is just normal multiplication.) Thus, the integral we wrote down is equivalent to
$$\int_a^b \|\mathbf{t}(\mathbf{r}(\mathbf{s}))\| \cdot \|\mathbf{r}'(s)\| ds$$
which is exactly the definition of the *scalar* line integral
$$\int_C \|\mathbf{t}\| ds$$
on the right-hand side of the identity you wanted to verify.

One key takeaway here: when evaluating line integrals (scalar or vector), you will most likely need to find a parameterization of the curve you are evaluating across.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! I have added some more information to my post. I don't know how to get the **t(r)** bit in the integral